# Outer join not working using phoenix jdbc driver with spring jdbc template in java

Tags: hbase, phoenix-framework, spring-jdbc

I need to do outer join on two tables and It works fine when I run it in SQuirrel client, but does not work when run it from java code using Phoenix JDBC Driver with Spring JDBC Template class.

While running in java with with Spring JDBC Template class, program gets hung and from log it looks like that it is trying to get connection, but not getting it.  However when I change it to Inner Join (in same SQL), it works.  So it does not look true that it is not able to get connection.  Below is what I see in logs where it gets hung:

```
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils : Fetching JDBC Connection
from DataSource
```

and below is SQL which I am running:

```
select acct.internal_account_id, acct.effective_date,
count(alrt.node_id) as alert_count 
from ACCOUNT_CONTEXT acct 
left outer join ( select internal_account_id, effective_date, node_id
from ALERT_CONTEXT where node_id in (1,2,5,6,7,8,24,58,59,75) ) as
alrt on acct.internal_account_id=alrt.internal_account_id and
acct.effective_date=alrt.effective_date where acct.internal_account_id
in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and acct.effective_date = ?  group by
acct.internal_account_id, acct.effective_date
```

Comment: Are you able to look up and paste any logs from your hbase server(s)? Presumably if it's trying to get a connection to HBase, you should see something in your HBase Master log...